# MySQL: how to select ID's with certain values in column

Tags: mysql

```
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    | ID        | Package      |   Date   | Amount |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     1     |      2       |2000/09/10|  2000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     1     |      4       |2002/09/20|  3000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     1     |      3       |2012/10/01|  5000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     1     |      4       |2012/10/01|  1000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     2     |      2       |2012/10/01|  2000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     2     |      4       |2012/10/01|  5000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     3     |      2       |2012/10/01|  3000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
    |     3     |      3       |2012/10/01|  5000  |
    +-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

For example, I have this table called 'Packages'.

Every ID is given one package on multiple dates which contain (amount) of items. When an ID receives  more than 1 package, there are multiple rows with the same ID.

I would like to select all ID's that have received both Package 2 and 4. In this case, I want mySQL to return ID 1 and 2, since ID 3 only has Package 2 but not 4.

I have used this query:

```
select
ID
from Packages
where Package = 2 and Package = 4
```

But when I use this, i get "No Results".

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one canonical way to do this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Packages
WHERE Package IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Package) = 2;
```

The basic idea is to restrict to only rows having the two packages of interest, then aggregate by `ID` and assert that the distinct remaining package count is 2.  This implies that your requirement is being met.

Answer (score 0):

select
ID
from Packages
where Package in(2,4)

Comment: kk .. i think its wrong

Comment: I think this would some rows which should not be part of correct result, like row with id 3 according to given table in ques.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a double select. The way you wrote your code, you select rows where the value is simultaneously 2 and 4. That cannot happen hence the empty result set you're getting back.

Try a nested select e.g.

```
Select id from packages where id in (select id, package from packages where package='2') and  package ='4'
```

You should also be able to use intersect. See https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php

More simply you can do

```
Select id from packages where package in (2,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select * from packages
where id in (select distinct id
from  (select distinct id from packages where package=2) a
 join (select distinct id from packages where package=4) b
   on (a.id = b.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM Packages WHERE Package = 2  
INTERSECT  
SELECT id FROM Packages WHERE Package = 4;
```

(Semicolon only at the end)
I hope this should work